# Ways to store php into a data source (not mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there is any kind of alternative to MySQL DB's.

It would be great if I could use MySQL db's but i don't want to ask the user to create a db as they'd find it to complicated and give up (non-web savvy target market). I cant store the data on one of mine remotely as there is just too much data and that's asking for trouble.

Also, the target market for my product are people that use one host. This host they use does not allow users to create MySQL db's. So I'm looking for an alternative where I can store personal data for the users to read and write. Maybe something that PHP can read and write to?

Any suggestions?

Is it possible to have a normal DB (Microsoft access DB file) on the server and PHP read/write to that?

Comment: You can consider using normal files

Comment: How large, in terms of records, do you think this will be?

Comment: [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)? That's an SQL-database stored in a file. Which has its downsides but simplifies usage.

Comment: SQLite is a good solution for single-user access. Also, if you encapsulate your database access, and use standard queries (not taking advantage of any extensions), you could easily provide the option of MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite or some other solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)?

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world.

Comment: Or do you want to avoid _all_ SQL databases?

Comment: The first I've heard about SQLite. Looks like I've got some researching to do. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Additional bonus: SQLite support is enabled by default in current versions of PHP. No need to install any additional binaries.

Answer (score 1):

sqlite is your choice:

In contrast to other database management systems, SQLite is not a separate process that is accessed from the client application, but an integral part of it.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php